# Concat a field in mysql with a computed field alias in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this query example:

```
SELECT users.name AS name, 2*2 AS field_aliases FROM users WHERE id > 0;
```

I need concat the users.name AND field_aliases, something like this, but it's not working:

```
SELECT CONCAT(users.name, \' \', field_aliases), 2*2 AS field_aliases FROM users WHERE id > 0;
```

How can I solve it? I have this error right now:

> Unknown column 'field_aliases' in 'field list'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use column alias directly in the same select list unless in a outer query. Change your query to be like below

```
SELECT CONCAT(users.name, \' \', 2*2), 
2*2 AS field_aliases 
FROM users 
WHERE id > 0;
```

(OR) access the column in a outer query like

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(users.name, \' \', field_aliases)
FROM (
SELECT users.name, 
2*2 AS field_aliases 
FROM users 
WHERE id > 0) xx;
```

Comment: Thanks, but the 2*2 operation is just an example.

Comment: @chemitaxis, the only way is to use the expression directly (or) use a outer query.

Comment: Ok, I will do in my client code in other way, but thanks.